# Python Pandas: How to drop the *correct* duplicate row?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
ID, Customer, Status,  Score, Size
01, Cust-A,   NaN,     100,   A
01, Cust-A,   Valid,   100,   A
02, Cust-B,   Invalid, 80,    B
02, Cust-B,   Invalid, NaN,   B
03, Cust-C,   Valid,   95,    C
04, Cust-D,   Invalid, 76,    NaN
04, Cust-D,   NaN,     76,    NaN
...
```

And so on.

How can I drop the *correct* row?

I'd like to drop the first row in the case of ID-01, and the second of ID-02, in the case of ID-04 I'd like to keep the first one since its the one with less NaNs

Comment: What if there are same number of missing values (or no missing values) for some IDs?

Comment: I don't know, its a good general question. In the dataset I'm cleaning there is not such condition as everything having values. What I've seen is that when there are duplicates, there's a row which has one or more missing values, and that the same columns have values they're the same. But your's is a great question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to calculate the total number of missing values for each ID, extract the index of the minimum missing values (with `idxmin()`) and use the index to subset your original data frame:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).apply(lambda g: g.isnull().sum(axis=1).idxmin())]

#   ID  Customer     Status  Score  Size
#1  1     Cust-A      Valid  100.0     A
#2  2     Cust-B    Invalid   80.0     B
#4  3     Cust-C      Valid   95.0     C
#5  4     Cust-D    Invalid   76.0   NaN
```